# VBA CODE FOR A VALUE IN A COMBOBOX TO SELECT A WORKSHEET

Tags: android

I have created a userform with multiple text boxes and a combo box in the same userform.
Now I would like to populate the combobox with different vehicle registration numbers so that when I select a vehicle number in the combo box, the data I enter in the userform should go to a particular worksheet of the vehicle selected.
Can you please assist with the code.

Private sub cmdSave_click()
`your text`eRow = sheet1.cells(Rows count, 1).end(xlup).offset(1, 0).Row
`your text`Sheet1.cells(eRow, 1).value = txtdate.value
`your text`sheet1.cells(eRow, 2).value=  =txtDescription.value
`your text`Sheet1.cells(eRow, 3).value=  = txtRemarks.
`your text`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.